# JasperReports, Subreports row height synchronization

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have 2 subreports, each report contains information for one column of what is going to be the result table. As some entries are quite lengthy I gave the rows of both subreports a same generic height size that worked fine enough for the hurry, but now it looks quite ugly so they want me to change it. So I was wondering if is there a way to coordinate both subreports, so that the one with the tallest cell of a given entry dictates the width of all the row and it sends that information to the other subreport to adjust the size of that same entry, just like it would happen on a regular table in just one subreport. If this is possible or do I have to use iText to make it happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a lot with jasper reports and I've given this a lot of thought, but I can't come up with an answer for how to make the subreports communicate a section height. I had composed an answer about using a Java class to define a static height that you could set and get, but then realized that you can't specify anything other than a simple numeric value for the height, i.e. there would be nowhere to call the method to get the height.

So, I have two possible recommendations which may or may not work depending on the implementation details for your reports.

The first recommendation would be to use a single report if at all possible, or at least a single "bottom row" below the two subreports.

If that won't work, then you could try using a minimal height value for both subreport sections, but with a Stretch Type of "Relative to Tallest Object". Then, although they may not be the same height, at least they wouldn't be too big. Depending again on the details, this might accomplish what you need.

Let me know if this works or not, maybe I can think of something else.